# VBA - Copy Mutiple File (After Download 1..2..3..) by Count into a Folder

Tags: vba

I have need help to copy multiple file into a folder after download.

The file after download default rename as:

- Branch_A.xlsx
- Branch_A (1).xlsx
- Branch_A (2).xlsx

Here code normally i use but this code only copy one file to a folder.
I need the code can capture words "Branch_A" then count file and copy to folder Branch_A. The count file is fix 3 its will come 4..5..6..

```
Sub down1()
'RENAME FILE DOWNLOAD BY BRANCHES

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String

    
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Path_Down1")

'FROM DOWNLOAD - C:\Users\Downloads\
FromPath = Ws.Range("E11").Value

'TO FOLDER - D:\Inbound\Branch_A\
ToPath = Ws.Range("F11").Value

Ws.Activate
FileCopy FromPath, ToPath


End Sub
```

I search few website and found that the code can count the file base on extention but i don't know how to edit to count by name and copy to folder. Here sample code:

```
Sub sample()

    Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
    FolderPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Santosh\Desktop"

    path = FolderPath & "\*.xls"

    Filename = Dir(path)

    Do While Filename <> ""
       count = count + 1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    Range("Q8").Value = count
    'MsgBox count & " : files found in folder"
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you say _The count file is fix 3 its will come 4..5..6.._ what do you mean? Do the files need to be renamed? If so is **Q8** where the count of files is? Then it adds onto it and renames the file or what?

Comment: Hai Simon, sorry for typo. actually I want say The count file is "NOT FIX 3" its will come 4..5..6..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the code below something you're looking for? This is what I could come up with what made sense to me. If not please provide more information as to what the issue is.

```
Sub Down1()

    Dim FromFolder As String, ToFolder As String
    Dim FromPath As String, ToPath As String, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Path_Down1")
    FromFolder = ws.Range("E11").Value
    ToFolder = ws.Range("F11").Value
    Filename = Dir(FromFolder & "\*.xlsx")
    
    Do While Filename <> ""
        If InStr(Filename, "Branch_A") > 0 Then
            FromPath = FromFolder & "\" & Filename
            ToPath = ToFolder & "\" & Filename
            
            FileCopy FromPath, ToPath
        End If
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hai Simon, tanks a lot for helping me. I almost get what i want. I try edit the code but i still cannot get it.. here attachment and screen shot as per request for download the sample. (screen shot in excel)

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oQ3iY23f4RQtCIvkSibhVqxiX4Utfcvf?usp=sharing

Comment: Right so you don't want the files renamed you just want them straight copied and then counted? (I don't know where the counting is supposed to go but you can change that). Check the updated answer then.

Comment: Yup just want them straight copied. The counted no need.